# How to validate DOMDocument object

Tags: php, xml, dom

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load($url);
```

If I am expecting user to give any rssfeed link to get xml document, and user is trying to give any random link which doesn't contain any xml document. It will certainly display an error or warning.

How can I validate this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `libxml_use_internal_errors` to handle the errors by yourself. Example from http://php.net/manual/de/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php

```
// enable user error handling
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// load the document
$doc = new DOMDocument;

if (!$doc->load('file.xml')) {
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        // handle errors here
    }

    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much redreggae. You have saved my time. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return value of load to check for errors and suppress the output with `@`

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
if (@$rss->load($url) == false) {
    //error...
}
```

Comment: Even now its displaying warning "Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: EntityRef: expecting".

Comment: Have you set an own error handler with set_error_handler?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$errors = array();
set_error_handler(function ($number, $error) use (&$errors) {
    if (preg_match('#^DOMDocument::load\(\):#', $error)) {
        $errors[] = $error;
    }
});

$url = '';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
if ($doc->load($url) === false) {
    // handle errors from $errors
}

restore_error_handler();
```